# Schengen visa with adverse credit report

Tags: schengen, europe

I will be traveling to Europe with my husband that has an EU passport. I would need to apply either for a Schengen visa or entry visa.

If you have defaults/judgements on your credit report will this effect whether or not your visa gets denied?

Comment: You don't state which country you are from. In answer to your question, **I'd guess** they would never look at your "credit report".  (Don't forget, "credit reports" are just a stupid database that a private company owned by banks, runs, so they can make more money.)

Comment: What do you mean by “entry visa”? A visas for a non-Schengen country like the UK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the consulate specifically asked for a credit report (and I would be very surprised if they did), they won't actively seek this information (and they would have to pay for it, too). There is just not enough time and resources for this level of diligence on each visa application.

In your case, since you are the spouse of an EU citizen and traveling with him, it should be even easier to get the visa. In principle, you shouldn't be asked to provide any information about your finances, only to prove your relationship with your husband (marriage certificate, possibly a legalized translation). If the consulate does ask for more information or wants to collect a fee, you can try reminding them of the rules, maybe by providing a link [to the official EU webpage about this](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm).

Note that these rules only necessarily apply to countries *other than the country of your husband's nationality* (this is somewhat counter-intuitive but does make sense in the general EU framework). Per the website above:

> If you reside outside the EU and your non-EU family members accompany you or travel to the EU country of your nationality, EU cross-border rules do not necessarily apply and visa fees might be charged.

The rules about where to apply for the visa are the same, i.e. you should apply to the consulate of the country where you will be staying the longest or, if staying for the same time in several countries, to the consulate of the first country you will enter.

Comment: Thanks Relaxed! I will have a look at the link you provided. My husband has an Austrian Passport and so does my son so I will make sure to go to the Austrian Consulate for my visa.

Comment: Does the same rules still apply if you're travelling with an EU spouse on where you're staying the longest? Or would it be fine to just go to the Austrian Consolate and get my Visa from them?

Comment: @Michelle I forgot to mention that the rule *does not apply to your husband's country* but to all other EU countries. So you do need to apply to the consulate of the country you are staying the longest and hopefully this isn't Austria, otherwise other rules might apply (which might or might not be easier). I will edit the answer.